# Как Swiper'у задать центральный слайд?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, swiper

В Swiper есть настройка "centeredSlides: true,", но она применяется сначала к первому слайду и при этом остается пустое место слева.

1. Как задать настройку "centeredSlides: true," с самого начала, чтобы она давалась 1 или 2ому слайду, но при этом не было пустого места.
2. Как избавиться от пустого места, чтобы там был последний или первый слайд в зависимости от решения для пункта 1

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/udnj7y?file=%2Findex.html%3A76%2C7-76%2C28

Пытался задать loop,  но настройка теперь закидывает налево последний слайд а справа слайд пропадает до прокрутки

Comment: Нашел initialSlide - задать активный слайд, но проблема теперь в том, что слайдер начинается теперь со 2 слайда, но мне надо чтобы с первого, но активным был вторым

Comment: Я не могу почему-то применить свои изменения на Кодсэндбоксе, в общем думаю нужно loop: true; поставить, чтобы цикличность была?

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи писал вышел насчет лупа